# Transfer Access 2010 query results to Excel 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using the following to transfer an Access 2010 query result to an Excel 2010 worksheet:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, qdfQRY.Name, strResult, True
```

The name of the worksheet I want to export to is the same as the name of the query used.  The problem is that if the query name is `AI-SVAL-DACA PV Param Chk` the name of the worksheet is `AI_SVAL_DACA_PV_Param_Chk`.  How can I prevent the name change from occurring?

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 options.  The first being the obvious and probably not what you want is to name you query Sheet1.  The second is to add code to rename the tab by using something similar to the following:

```
Dim xlbook As Object
Dim xlsheet As Object

Set xlbook = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlsheet = xlbook.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\username\Desktop\Test.xlsx")

With xlsheet
 .Activate
 .sheets(1).Name = "ABC"  '< apply name to 1st Tab
 .Save
End With

'Quit_and_housekeep
xlbook.Quit    '< Quit Excel
Set xlsheet = Nothing
Set xlbook = Nothing
```